# git commit using ssh signing key shows error

Tags: git, ssh, key, digital-signature

```
> git commit -m "comment"
error: unsupported value for gpg.format: ssh fatal: bad config
variable 'gpg.format' in file '/home/user/.gitconfig' at line 11
```

```
> git config --list
 
[user]
    email = email@gmail.com
    name = username
    signingkey = /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
[gpg "x509"]
    program = smimesign
[gpg]
    program = gpg
    format = ssh
```

i'm not able to commit using git due to this error.

what do i need to do ?
i'm using linux mint.

Comment: ssh signature support was merged for 2.34, what's `git --version` say?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+unsupported+value+for+gpg.format%3A+ssh+fatal%3A+bad+config